# Object-Orientated Coin Acceptor with CLI in Python

Tags: python

My assignment is:
Create object-oriented Python program with two files: "main.py" and "coin_acceptor.py".
Coin acceptor purpose is to count the amount of inserted coins and the value.
User should be able to insert coins and also return coins.

```
coin_acceptor.py
Coin acceptor should have following aspects:
Properties
__amount: int
__value: float
Methods
insertCoin(value: float) -> None
getAmount() -> int
getValue() -> float
returnCoins() -> float
```

main.py

Imports the "CoinAcceptor" class from the "coin_acceptor.py" file and creates one object from it and add program logic into the main program which allows the user to insert the coins via CLI.

The main program logic should welcome the user to the program and then start asking for coins continuously. If the inserted coin value is 0, the program should return the coins. And continue. And in case the value is -1, the program should exit and thank the user for using the program.

Example program run:

```
Welcome to coin acceptor program.
Insert new coin by typing it's value (0 returns the money, -1 exits the program): 2
Inserting...
Currently inserted amount of coins: 1 and value: 2.0€
Insert new coin by typing it's value (0 returns the money, -1 exits the program): 0.5
Inserting...
Currently inserted amount of coins: 2 and value: 2.5€
Insert new coin by typing it's value (0 returns the money, -1 exits the program): 0
Returning coins...
Coins returned, total value: 2.5€.
Currently inserted amount of coins: 0 and value: 0€
Insert new coin by typing it's value (0 returns the money, -1 exits the program): 1
Inserting...
Currently inserted amount of coins: 1 and value: 1.0€
Insert new coin by typing it's value (0 returns the money, -1 exits the program): -1
Thank you for using the program.
```

My code so far:
coin_acceptor.py

```
#Properties
class CoinAcceptor:
    __amount: int
    __value: float

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.__amount = 0
        self.__value = 0
        return None
#Methods
    def insertCoin(self, value: float)-> None:
        self.__amount += 1
        self.__value += value
        return None

    def getAmount(self)-> int:
        return self.__amount

    def getValue(self)-> float:
        return self.__value

    def returnCoins(self)-> float:
        amount = self.__amount
        value = self.__value
        self.__amount = int
        self.__value = float
        return value
```

main.py

```
from coin_acceptor import CoinAcceptor
class Main:
    print("Welcome to coin acceptor program.")
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        # creating 1 object
        coin_acceptor = CoinAcceptor()
        #coin_acceptor.insertCoin()
        while True:
            coin_value = float(input("Insert new coin by typing it's value (0 returns the money, -1 exits the program): "))
        
            if coin_value == -1:
                print("Thank you for using the program.", end="")
                break
            elif coin_value == 0:
                value = coin_acceptor.returnCoins()
                print("Returning coins...")
                
                print("Coins returned, total value: ", value,"€", sep="")
                print("Currently inserted amount of coins: ", coin_acceptor.getAmount(), " and value: ", coin_acceptor.getValue(),"€", sep="")
                continue
            else:
                coin_acceptor.insertCoin(coin_value)
                print("Inserting...")
                print("Currently inserted amount of coins: ", coin_acceptor.getAmount(), " and value: ", coin_acceptor.getValue(),"€", sep="")
        
        return None
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Main()
```

After running it in VS Code my output is as follows:

```
Welcome to coin acceptor program.
Insert new coin by typing it's value (0 returns the money, -1 exits the program): 1
Inserting...
Currently inserted amount of coins: 1 and value: 1.0€
Insert new coin by typing it's value (0 returns the money, -1 exits the program): 1
Inserting...
Currently inserted amount of coins: 2 and value: 2.0€
Insert new coin by typing it's value (0 returns the money, -1 exits the program): 0
Returning coins...
Coins returned, total value: 2.0€
Currently inserted amount of coins: <class 'int'> and value: <class 'float'>€
Insert new coin by typing it's value (0 returns the money, -1 exits the program): 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

line 12, in insertCoin
self.__amount += 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'type' and 'int'

Comment: Look where you set `self.__amount`

Comment: What's that in `returnCoins`? Assigning a type object to an int/float variable doesn't make sense. Do you mean `self.__amount = int` -> `self.__amount = 0` and `self.__value = float` -> `self.__value = 0`?

Comment: @Fractalism, i guess there is my problem. As my output don't print properly neither, after money returned and then don't start calculating amount of money inserted and value of it.

Comment: Thank you to all of you got it work the problem layed in returnCoins and if i changed it like that it worked:        self.__amount = 0
self.__value = 0.0